How to import data in a specific cell from a website into excel?
I am trying to use importXML to import data from a website into excel but I am getting empty content!
The website is https://explorer.spectre-network.org/ and I am trying to import Hashrate value.
Copy xpath and full path is not working.
=importxml("https://explorer.spectre-network.org/","/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tr[7]/td[2]")

Would anyone help please?
Thanks in advance
=importxml("https://explorer.spectre-network.org/","/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tr[7]/td[2]")


the site is dynamically loaded. and there is an api

Get the data directly from the API.
In cell A1:
=WEBSERVICE("https://api.spectre-network.org/info/hashrate?stringonly=false")

This will retrieve the response from the API. The response will look something like this:
{"hashrate": 1.813477862e-05}

In cell A2:
=VALUE(MID(A1, FIND(":", A1) + 1, FIND("}", A1) - FIND(":", A1) - 1))*1000000

This parses the response, extracting the numeric value and scaling it so that it's consistent with the units used on the website.
